# What is best way to insert post,tag,category to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi I have these tables :

```
Table Name | column 1 | column 2 | ...   
Posts       | ID       | Title    | description  
Tags        | ID       | Name  
Categories  | ID       | Title    | Parent-ID  
Post-Tag    | ID       | post-id  | tag-id  
Post-Cat    | ID       | post-id  | cat-id
```

how can I insert 1 post with tags & categories?
I can insert a new post like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Posts (title, description) VALUES ( :title, :desc)");

$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindParam(':desc', $description);

$post_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

I have only one post per time but maybe have five tags & 2 categories so
how I check a tag/category exists & if exists get its ID & if not insert it then get id & insert it in the Post-tag/Post-cat table?!

Comment: you tagged as pdo yet you're using `bind_param()` which is mysqli_, and then `lastInsertId()` which is PDO. The question is unclear as to which api is really used to connect with. Those different apis don't intermix.

Comment: Fixed it. A problem occurred when copy code from my system

Comment: to somewhat answer this, you need to check if something exists using `SELECT` and a `rowCount()`.

Comment: Do it exactly like you explained. Step by step, with one query for each step.There is no kind of query which allow you to do all the steps togehter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little bit of sample-code to give you an idea how it may work...

```
<?php
class PostRepository {

    public static function tagExists($tag) {
        // do your query here and return tag-id if it exists and false if it doesnt exist
    }

    public static function insertTag($tag) {
        // do your insert query here and return the inserted id and false on failure
    }

    public static function insertPostTag($id_post, $id_tag) {
        // do your insert query here and return the inserted id
    }

    public static function insertPost($title, $description, $arr_tags) {

        $conn = PdoHelper::getPdoInstance(); // get your conn-obj however...

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `Posts`  (title, description) VALUES ( :title, :desc)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
        $stmt->bindParam(':desc', $description);

        $post_id = $conn->lastInsertId();

        foreach($arr_tags as $tag) {
            $existing_tag = self::tagExists($tag);
            if(!$existing_tag) {
                $existing_tag = self::insertTag($tag);
            }
            self::insertPostTag($post_id, $existing_tag);
        }

    }
}
```